# When searching the data in the filter I want to show "No data to display" when search results with empty dataset in Angular SlickGrid

Tags: angular, typescript, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

When searching the data in the filter I want to show "No data to display" when search results with empty dataset

#### Context

When searching the data in the filter I want to show "No data to display" when search results with empty dataset

#### Expected Behavior

show "No data to display" Message instead of empty one

#### Current Behavior

It shows empty

#### Environment

Angular - 8.2.14, Angular-Slickgrid - 2.22.4 ,TypeScript  - 3.7

Comment: this is now built-in Angular-Slickgrid, see the Update below for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE 2020-11-18

This is now part of Angular-Slickgrid (since version `2.23.1`) and is enabled by default, you can also disable it with the flag `enableEmptyDataWarningMessage`. There are also few options you can provide with the new property `emptyDataWarning` Grid Options (see [EmptyWarning](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/emptyWarning.interface.ts) interface for more info)

I also did not use the code shown with the absolute positioning since that was causing issues, instead the approach is to search for the DOM element with class of `.grid-canvas` and append a `<div>` to that container, so that it's always at the correct position.

#### Original Answer

It's not possible in SlickGrid, it will only displays data that must fit in the cells.

However you have other alternatives, I think the best you can do is to display your text in a span in the middle (or top) of the grid. You can take a look at the SlickGrid [Example - Yahoo Search](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading-yahoo.html) it shows the  "Buffering..." in the middle of the screen. The final piece is to know when to display it, you can use the DataView `onRowCountChanged` event, which will provide you the item count.

```html
<span class="empty-data" [hidden]="hasFilteredData">
   No data to display
</span>

<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid4" 
    [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" 
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [dataset]="dataset" 
    (sgOnRowCountChanged)="handleOnRowCountChanged($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

```js
export class MyDemo {
  hasFilteredData = true;

  handleOnRowCountChanged(e, args) {
    this.hasFilteredData = args.current > 0;
  }
}
```

To position the empty data `<span>` message, you can take a look at the [Yahoo Example](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example6-ajax-loading-yahoo.html#L132) I provided earlier, they use something like this (you can use relevant code)

```js
loader.onDataLoading.subscribe(function () {
      if (!loadingIndicator) {
        loadingIndicator = $("<span class='loading-indicator'><label>Buffering...</label></span>").appendTo(document.body);
        var $g = $("#myGrid");

        loadingIndicator
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .css("top", $g.position().top + $g.height() / 2 - loadingIndicator.height() / 2)
            .css("left", $g.position().left + $g.width() / 2 - loadingIndicator.width() / 2);
      }

      loadingIndicator.show();
    });
```

Taking pieces of it, I can achieve what is shown below

```js
@Component({
  styles: ['.empty-data { color: orange; z-index: 9999; position: absolute; }'],
  templateUrl: './my-demo.component.html'
})
export class MyDemo {
  hasFilteredData = true;

  handleOnRowCountChanged(e, args) {
    this.hasFilteredData = args.current > 0;

    const $grid = $('#grid4');

    $('.empty-data')
      .css("top", $grid.position().top + 90)
      .css("left", $grid.position().left + 10);
  }

   // or with pure JS
   /*
   const emptyDataElm = document.querySelector<HTMLSpanElement>('.empty-data');
   const grid = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#grid4');
   const gridPosition = grid.getBoundingClientRect();
   emptyDataElm.style.top = `${gridPosition.top + 90}px`;
   emptyDataElm.style.left = `${gridPosition.left + 10}px`;
   */
}
```

[image]

New [LIVE DEMO](https://ghiscoding.github.io/angular-slickgrid-demos/#/clientside)

You could also make it fully reusable by moving the entire code into a utility service so that you won't have to copy the same code over and over in all in your grids. We can also use only the DOM to create/show/hide the message to be fully dynamic and code it once.

```html
<span class="empty-data">
   No data to display
</span>

<angular-slickgrid>...</angular-slickgrid>
```

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './my-demo.component.html'
})
export class MyDemo {
  handleOnRowCountChanged(e, args) {
    // display warning when there's no filtered data
    utility.showEmptyDataMessage('#grid4', 'No data to display', args.current === 0 /*, { color: 'red' } */);
  }
}
```

```
  // utility.ts

  /**
   * Display a warning of empty data when the filtered dataset is empty
   * NOTE: to make this code reusable, you could (should) move this code into a utility service
   * @param gridSelector - HTML Selector of the grid <div>
   * @param emptyMessage - empty data message to display in the <span>
   * @param isShowing - are we showing the message?
   * @param options - any styling options you'd like to pass like the text color
   */
  export function showEmptyDataMessage(gridSelector: string, emptyMessage: string, isShowing = true, options?: { color: string; class: 'empty-data' }) {
    const emptyDataClassName = options && options.class || 'empty-data';
    let emptyDataElm = document.querySelector<HTMLSpanElement>(`.${emptyDataClassName}`);
    const grid = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>(gridSelector);

    if (!emptyDataElm) {
      emptyDataElm = document.createElement('span');
      emptyDataElm.className = emptyDataClassName;
      emptyDataElm.textContent = emptyMessage;
      document.body.appendChild(emptyDataElm);
    }

    if (isShowing) {
      const gridPosition = grid.getBoundingClientRect();
      emptyDataElm.style.top = `${gridPosition.top + 90}px`;
      emptyDataElm.style.left = `${gridPosition.left + 10}px`;
      emptyDataElm.style.color = options && options.color || 'orange';
      emptyDataElm.style.zIndex = '9999';
      emptyDataElm.style.position = 'absolute';
      emptyDataElm.style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
      emptyDataElm.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```